# Rails 3 + Cucumber - Common steps "go to page" not defined/recognized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I am starting to use cucumber for high level testing. I have this defined in my gem file:

```
group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', '< 0.8.3', :require => false
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'#, '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat'#, '0.7.1'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

and this in my test.feature

```
  Scenario: Go to contact
    Given I go to contact page
    Then I should see contact page
```

When I run `bundle exec cucumber features` I have to define all the steps. Isn't `go to page` supposed to be a build-in defined step? It seems that capybara and cucumber are not working together. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These steps are no longer defined in more recent `cucumber-rails` versions. See here for a better explanation of why: http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off.

Comment: Thanks! There are just so many changes happening (like Cucumber moving away from webrat, etc) that many tutorials out there are outdated. You end up not knowing what is really going on.

Comment: Yup, I agree :) I even wrote a book on Rails (Rails 3 in Action) which suffered from this change. I would really look into using the "new" style of syntax as Aslak recommends, given he is the expect on this.

Comment: I am trying to digest the changes 'without the training wheels'. Do you know in my simple case, what is the best practice to write my scenario and steps? Should I define my own `go to` to map to `visit` or? It is kind of confusing.

Comment: im not sure what the new paths.rb looks like but you can chck older versions of paths to base your "go to" step. it is discouraged however, as pointed out in ryan's link - your steps shouldn't be that brittle.

Comment: if you really want to follow the 'old way' though, your step is off by a preposition - it should be (usually) Given I go to the contact page (assuming you have contact_path defined in your routes) or you can edit your support/env/paths.rb to reflect this route

Comment: I would like to learn the best practice ('correct' way) of doing it. But even after reading that link, I am not quite sure what is the recommended way to go about doing it.

Comment: I also want to include http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/11/07/modern-cucumber-and-rails-no-more-training-wheels/ this as a good follow up to the previous link.

Comment: I've found that with this old/new way of thinking, having a step that does nothing more than visit a page is becoming less common.  This is sometimes wrapped up entirely in a flow.  In the example given, "  When he logs in" contains the visit step.

Comment: You can still do it the old way using [cucumber-rails-training-wheels](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails-training-wheels)